# Node.js Nginx POST request

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a Node.js server with Express running on the same machine where Nginx is installed. This is my nginx code in sites-enabled:

```
upstream project {
    server 192.168.0.102:3100;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://project;
    }
}
```

With this config, when I type my domain on a public computer, the first page of my website shows up, so thats okay. But the webpage is a form where I should be able to upload data to my server, and when I press upload in my website, nothing happens. This is my sudo-code:

```
app.get("/", function(request,response){
    //Code to send html page. This is the part where it runs fine.
});
app.post("/package/upload", function(request,response){
    //Code to read from request.body and request.files and save uploaded file to my server. 
    //Nothing happens when I try to upload through a normal XMLHTTP object in my website. 
});
```

I'm been working on servers for some time, but its my first time using nginx for server optimization and load-balancing. Can somebody help me what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post your HTTP request/responses? Would help determining if its a problem on the nginx side or node, (or possibly even with the request itself)

Comment: so, I looked at my log file and it was the client_max_body property that was set too low that nginx wasn't able to let big POST requests come through. Now I have it working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment, not enough rep)

It looks like you've setup the proxy_pass only on `/`. Have you tried defining your POST location `/package/upload` and the corresponding proxy_pass?

What do you see when you look at the Network panel in your browsers developer tools when you try to upload? HTTP Status codes help a ton when debugging.